# Need a MySQL Query to Show Parents that have children as well as Parents with no Children

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that currently grabs me all the categories and their subcategories from a three-column table.   Each row in the table contains a catid, a category and a parentid (zero if there is no parent).

```
SELECT t1.category AS lev1, 
   t2.category as lev2, 
   t3.category as lev3, 
   t4.category as lev4
FROM categories AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.parentid = t1.catid
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.parentid = t2.catid
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS t4 ON t4.parentid = t3.catid
WHERE t1.parentid = 0  AND t1.cat_type = 'content'
ORDER BY lev1, lev2, lev3, lev4
```

It returns me a collection of data as follows:

```
sample cat 1 | sample cat 4 
sample cat 1 | sample cat 5 
sample cat 1 | sample cat 6 
sample cat 2 | sample cat 7 
sample cat 2 | sample cat 8 
sample cat 3 | sample cat 9  |  sample cat 11
sample cat 3 | sample cat 10 |  sample cat 12
```

The problem is that I need the main parent categories to be displayed as if they had no children.  So the returned data should look like"

```
sample cat 1 |               |
sample cat 1 | sample cat 5  |
sample cat 1 | sample cat 6  |
sample cat 2 |               |
sample cat 2 | sample cat 7  |
sample cat 2 | sample cat 8  |
sample cat 3 |               |
sample cat 3 | sample cat 9  |
sample cat 3 | sample cat 9  |  sample cat 11
sample cat 3 | sample cat 10 |
sample cat 3 | sample cat 10 |  sample cat 12
```

I modified the query to get the top-level Parent Cats by themselves, but clearly this is not the right way.

```
    SELECT category AS lev1,    catid   AS lev1catid,
       '' as lev2,  '' as lev2catid,
       '' as lev3,  '' as lev3catid FROM categories WHERE parentid = 0  AND cat_type = 'content' UNION ALL

SELECT t1.category AS lev1,     t1.catid AS lev1catid, 
       t2.category as lev2,     t2.catid as lev2catid,
          t3.category as lev3,  t3.catid as lev3catid
    FROM cat
    egories AS t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.parentid = t1.catid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.parentid = t2.catid
    WHERE t1.parentid = 0  AND t1.cat_type = 'content'
    ORDER BY lev1, lev2, lev3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a recursive hierarchical query to solve this in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

One method is `union all`:

```
SELECT t1.category AS lev1, t2.category as lev2, t3.category as lev3, t4.category as lev4
FROM categories t1 JOIN
     categories t2
     ON t2.parentid = t1.catid JOIN
     categories t3
     ON t3.parentid = t2.catid JOIN
     categorie t4
     ON t4.parentid = t3.catid
WHERE t1.parentid = 0 AND t1.cat_type = 'content'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.category AS lev1, t2.category as lev2, t3.category as lev3, NULL as lev4
FROM categories t1 JOIN
     categories t2
     ON t2.parentid = t1.catid JOIN
     categories t3
     ON t3.parentid = t2.catid
WHERE t1.parentid = 0 AND t1.cat_type = 'content'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.category AS lev1, t2.category as lev2, NULL as lev3, NULL as lev4
FROM categories t1 JOIN
     categories t2
     ON t2.parentid = t1.catid 
WHERE t1.parentid = 0 AND t1.cat_type = 'content'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.category AS lev1, NULL as lev2, NULL as lev3, NULL as lev4
FROM categories t1
WHERE t1.parentid = 0 AND t1.cat_type = 'content';
```